# How to move a SSRS-Chart more to left

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have a Bar Chart in SSRS. On the left I have a lot of white space how to decrease it? I want to move the y-axis for to the left and the first bar chart too.

I did not found any options in the properties of the chart.

[image: see here]

Answer (score 1):

The space between the Axis and the first bar is controlled by the Side Margin property in the Axis' Options.

Right click on the Axis and set the Side Margin property to Disabled.

Or you could use the Chart Axis Property page and set the Margin to False.

[image]

Comment: Great advise. Is it possible to set a distance manuelly? Like 1cm or so.